# mongodb operation very slow when using replica set

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, replicaset

I'm running MongoDB 2.4.5 and recently I've started digging into Replica Set to get some kind of redundancy.

I started same mongo instance with --replSet parameter and also added an Arbiter to running Replica Set. What happened was writing to mongo slowed down significantly (from 15ms to 30-60ms, sometimes even around 300ms). As soon as I restarted it in not-replicaset-mode performance went back to normal.

Comment: You need to explain your "topolgy" and mainly the geographic distribution of nodes. But as a general case the ["write concern"](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/write-concern/) used is the key element here. Generally speaking the "default" case is asking for "acknowlegement" from all members of the set, rather than just the primary. So this is going to add time in general unless you "want" to change that.

Comment: i am using one primary and two secondary in replica set , and try write concern with w=0 and w=3. but inserting and fetching record are too slowly. what will be value of write concern, i am using pymongo as a client

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding here in the basic mechanics. It is not possible to use "w=0" AND "w=3"  unless you are actually talking about using "either" on separate "write" statements independantly. WriteConcern is a singular value either "global" or "individually set" per statement and you cannot "choose" between nodes. Also "w=3" seems really **wrong** considering you mention "one secondary" and then an "arbiter". An arbiter is "vote only" and neither stores data nor can become a primary. So "w=3" in that config would be waiting for acknowlegement that is not possible.